# Dividing values from a single column into 2 based on a rule

Tags: query

I am trying to create an SQL query to divide into 2 separate columns based on a rule. My table is as follows

```
Name   | Item ID  | Parent ID
-----  | -------- | ----------
A      | 1        | Null
B      | 2        | Null
C      | 3        | Null
D      | 4        | Null
A1     | 5        | 1
A2     | 6        | 1
A3     | 7        | 1
B1     | 8        | 2
B2     | 9        | 2
B3     | 10       | 2
```

Is it possible to have the values in the `[Name]` column be divided into 2 columns?

e.g. if the value of the `[Parent ID]` is `Null`, the value in `[Name]` column be in column 1 and if the value of `[Parent ID]` is `1`, it would be placed in column 2?

Please advice and thanks in advance!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 4):

Use a CASE statement in the column list to check if `ParentID` is `1` or `null`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fdc0d/1)

**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup**:

```
create table YourTable
(
    Name varchar(10),
    ItemID int,
    ParentID int
 );

 insert into YourTable(Name, ItemID, ParentID) values('A', 1, null);
 insert into YourTable(Name, ItemID, ParentID) values('B', 2, null);
 insert into YourTable(Name, ItemID, ParentID) values('C', 3, null);
 insert into YourTable(Name, ItemID, ParentID) values('D', 4, null);
 insert into YourTable(Name, ItemID, ParentID) values('A1', 5, 1);
 insert into YourTable(Name, ItemID, ParentID) values('A2', 6, 1);
 insert into YourTable(Name, ItemID, ParentID) values('A3', 7, 1);
 insert into YourTable(Name, ItemID, ParentID) values('B1', 8, 2);
 insert into YourTable(Name, ItemID, ParentID) values('B2', 9, 2);
 insert into YourTable(Name, ItemID, ParentID) values('B3', 10, 2);
```

**Query 1**:

```
select case when ParentID is null then T.Name end as Column1,
       case when ParentID = 1 then T.Name end as Column2
from YourTable as T;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/fdc0d/1/0)**:

```
| column1 | column2 |
|---------|---------|
|       A |  (null) |
|       B |  (null) |
|       C |  (null) |
|       D |  (null) |
|  (null) |      A1 |
|  (null) |      A2 |
|  (null) |      A3 |
|  (null) |  (null) |
|  (null) |  (null) |
|  (null) |  (null) |
```